# Extracting properties from parent class to its sub class

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following classes:

```
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Age {get;set;}
    }

    public class SubClass : ParentClass
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}

    }
```

and I have the following method:

```
    public void InsertSubClass(ParentClass parentClass)
    {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        subClass.Id = 1;
        subClass.Age = parentClass.Age;
        subClass.Name= parentClass.Name;


    }
```

How can I refactor this method in such a way that I dont need to assign the properties of the parameter ParentClass into properties of SubClass one by one?
Are there any alternative which is more efficient? or this is really how to do it? Im just thinking that if the properties are many, this could be tedious..

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: from the code posted it looks like you are creating two different instance. The `InsertSubClass` method looks more like a method that translates values between two classes. To give a better answer can you post how values are assigned to properties in `ParentClass`

Comment: Use constructor overloading. If properties are many then check which are minimal by which your class can run. Use abstraction if properties are increasing. If you dont need to assign for base means what? Give default values in those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this thing by creating copy constructor. Anyways you would have to assign parent class properties somewhere as casting wont work in this case.

Here is copy constructor way that assigns parent property in parent constructor.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ParentClass()
    {

    }

    //Copy constructor
    public ParentClass(ParentClass parentClass)
    {
        this.Name = parentClass.Name;
        this.Age = parentClass.Age;
    }
}

public class SubClass : ParentClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public SubClass(ParentClass parentClass, int id) : base(parentClass)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

And now method looks like this.

```
public static void InsertSubClass(ParentClass parentClass)
{
    SubClass subClass = new SubClass(parentClass, 1);
}
```

**Update**

If you can not make changes to your parent and child class then how about creating an extension method for the parent class in static class like below.

```
public static void ShallowConvert<T, U>(this T parent, U child)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in parent.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.CanWrite)
        {
            property.SetValue(child, property.GetValue(parent, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This might not work with private properties and fields.

Comment: Thanks Jenish, yes this will work, however the problem is the class ParentClass should not be modified.

Comment: @wuU If you don't want to change base class then overloading Cast will also not work. In that case you would have to assign a property one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign parent class to child's base object like this `child.base = parent`. Also you can not cast paret class to child like `var o = (child)parent; o.id=1;` All you can do is add constructor to child class that receives parent class and do work in that constructor.